# Adding 'Fade out/Fade in' to Responsive Media Queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm wondering how to add the **'Fade in/Fade out'** effects to elements that I make appear or disappear with a **responsive web site using CSS3 media queries**. I've figured out how to use `linear` transitions, but would really like to use a fade.

Comment: you need a sample code? & what do you really mean by responsive media queries?

Comment: `linear` is a timing-function (basically the function of a curve to make the animation appear as though it is moving at a certain speed at a certain time). Another timing-function is `east-in-out`. The reason I bring this up is because you can fade in/out with any easing function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition

Comment: Dave, Responsive Queries; as in CSS3 media Queries stating which styles effect/render which window size. Transitions applying to them such as this site; http://www.woostercollective.com

Comment: Jasper, yeah. I know I can fade/fade out without transitions, but I want to do it with them, think it'd be rad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with CSS you will need to use `transitions`. The only way I can think to fade in/out an element with CSS transitions would be to set the `opacity` to zero and then animate the `opacity` back to one, but you can't do this with CSS alone (you would need some JS to time the events properly):

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(this).width() <= 480) {
        //do code for less than 480px wide 
        $('#some-element').css('opacity', 0).addClass('transition').css('opacity', 1);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#some-element').removeClass('transition');
        }, 500);
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Where the `transition` CSS class would have the `transition` rule set:

```
.transition {
    -webkit-transition : opacity 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition : opacity 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition : opacity 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition : opacity 0.5s linear;
            transition : opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```